# OpenLayers 6 layer source parameter refresh problem

Tags: update, openlayers, refresh

I'm trying to refresh a source with some parameter. There is a text input control on the html page, I look forward to updating the map based on user input after clicking the button, but it doesn't work.

The code is below:

```
var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      ratio: 1,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/newyork/wms',
      params: {         
            "LAYERS": 'newyork:viewStation',
            "viewparams": 'id:'+10
      }
    })
  });

var map =new ol.Map({
    target:'map',
    layers:[
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source:new ol.source.OSM()
        }),
        untiled
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        center:new ol.proj.fromLonLat([-73.9,40.8]),
        zoom:10
    })
});

function repaint(){
    var num=document.getElementById('textfield').value;
    untiled.getSource().updateParams({'id':num});
    untiled.getSource().refresh();
}

var bnt=document.getElementById('button');
bnt.addEventListener('click',repaint)
```

Comment: If you want to update viewparams you will need `untiled.getSource().updateParams({"viewparams": 'id:'+num});`

Comment: It works! Thank you Mike

Answer (score 1):

To update `viewparams` you will need

```
untiled.getSource().updateParams({"viewparams": 'id:'+num});
```